# What is a "NuMA protein"?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology

I just got out of a lecture on mitosis and this part was incredibly confusing. After searching my textbook it doesn't cover it that well either.

The professor mentioned a NUMA protein that is released after NEBD, and that it helps form more Microtubules. I don't really understand how it does this.

Is it just a protein that sits in the pericentriolar matrix and encourages microtubule nucleation? Or is it a a kinase that deactivates some GAPs that destabilize microtubules?

Also, if you would like, there's also this study question I feel is sort of related: What are two proteins located in the pericentriolar matrix that encourage microtubule nucleation?

I feel like one of them is the y-tubulin ring complex. Would the other be NUMA?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: you should ask your professor if you have doubts about a lecture. you can read about NuMA [here](http://jcs.biologists.org/content/107/6/1389.full.pdf)